# Can't send Raw Telegram Request through CAPL on CANoe

Tags: request, diagnostics, capl, canoe, uds

EDIT: The main problem has been solved, but I stilla have a question, check the third attempt to see it.

I'm trying to send a Diagnostic Request that is not defined on my Diagnostic Description.

I have the following on my script:

```
 variables
{
    //Diagnostic Request that doesn't exist on the .cdd
    diagRequest ReadParameter Parameter_Req;
}

on preStart
{
  //Sets Diganostic Target just as it was configured
  diagSetTarget("DUT");
  
}

on key 's'
{
    //Setting request size to 3 bytes
//I asigned the size to a variable to be able to read which value it had after resizing if but
//everytime I got 0xFF9E or something like that the case is it seems the diagResize is not working
        diagResize(Parameter_Req,0x3);
    
    //Setting bytes on the request to creat 22 05 70 (read by identifier)
    Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(0,0x22);
    Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(1,0x05);
    Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(2,0x70);

    //Send Request
    diagSendRequest(Parameter_Req);
}
```

But the request is never sent, nothing new is seen on the Trace window. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? I tried this with a Diagnostic Request that is declared on the Diagnostic Description and it works the request is sent, so I know my diagnostic configuration is OK. Also, no error is reported by CANoe

Thanks for your help

Edit: I also tried this other way

```
variables
{
  byte ReadDID0570[3];
}

on preStart
{
  //Sets Diganostic Target just as it was configured
  diagSetTarget("DUT"); 
}

on key 's'
{
//Set bytes and Send Read Request
    ReadDID0570[0] = 0x22;
    ReadDID0570[1] = 0x05;
    ReadDID0570[2] = 0x70;

//Send request
DiagSendRequestPDU(ReadDID0570, elCount(ReadDID0570));
}
```

But the result the same absolutely nothing happens.

Edit After the suggestion of M. Spiller

```
variables
{
  diagRequest * Parameter_Req;
}

on preStart
{
  //Sets Diganostic Target just as it was configured
  diagSetTarget("DUT"); 
}

on key 's'
{
//Resize the request to three bytes
diagResize(Parameter_Req,0x3);

//Set bytes
Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(0,0x22);
Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(1,0x05);
Parameter_Req.SetPrimitiveByte(2,0x70);

//Send Request
diagSendRequest(Parameter_Req);
}
```

This worked! The request is sent, although is not showed in the Trace window, I know it was sent because the response could be seen on Trace. Now my only question is how can I use `diagGetLastResponse(Parameter_res);` and `on diagResponse Parameter_res`  using this same method to declare the response?

```
diagResponse * Parameter_Res;
```

Because those functions receive the name of the request/response declared on the Diagnostic Description, but using this method the type of request is * so how do I use it?

Comment: Why do you use a non-existing `diagRequest`? Does `diagRequest * Parameter_Req;` work?

Comment: Let me update the post with the results of using diagRequest * Parameter_Req; It worked a bit more, but it still is not working entirely

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken it does work now, but I still have a question how can I use `diagGetLastResponse(Parameter_res);` and `on diagResponse Parameter_res`  using this same method to declare the response?

`diagResponse * Parameter_Res;`

Because those functions receive the name of the request/response declared on the Diagnostic Description, but using this method the type of request is * so how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You have used `diagGetLastResponse(Parameter_res)` to save the response to the `Parameter_res` variable. Since this is a variable declared with `*`, you won't have access to the parameters as specified in your Diagnostic Description.
You can make use of the function `diagInterpretRespAs` to convert this response variable to a suitable class according to your description file. After this, you can use `diagGetParameter` to get the parameter with the resolution and offset considered.
Otherwise, you can simply use the raw response variable and use `diagGetPrimitiveByte` to access the bytes in the response.